# Is there any command to list all the GCP project quota in a single excel file with only top headers

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is there any command to list all the GCP project quota in a single excel file with only top headers. I tried to apply FOR loop on quota management however it gives me output with header included every time with new projects when appended.

gcloud compute project-info describe --flatten=quotas -- format='csv(quotas.metric,quotas.limit,quotas.usage)' will provide for one project. However require for all project on Org level and folder level in a single excel file.

Comment: There is no quota export at Org or folder level. It's per project. You have to build yourselves the script.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Yes, hence asking for assistance if anyone had created the script. I am not able to achieve the same

Answer (score 3):

I crafted this bash code that can help you in order to iterate all projects related with  the account used with GCloud ***feel free to modify this code according your use case***

```sh
#!/bin/bash
#unique header
echo "ProjectId,Metric,Quota,Usage"
gcloud projects list --format="csv[no-heading](projectId,name)" |\
while IFS="," read -r ID NAME
do
  RESULT=$(\
    gcloud compute project-info describe --project ${ID} \
    --flatten=quotas \
    --format="csv[no-heading](quotas.metric,quotas.limit,quotas.usage)")
  # Prefix ${ID} to each line in the result
  for LINE in ${RESULT}
  do
    echo ${ID},${LINE}
  done
done
```

it is important that the account authenticated has the role `project/viewer` over all projects associated, also  `Compute Engine API` must be enabled in the projects.

Having said that, you can create a service account associated per organization or by folder in order to get all necessary information.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: @Amit if this answer was useful please do not forget accept or upvote