# gcloud: Can we get GCP Quota details in tabular format

Tags: google-cloud-platform

simple script to list all the GCP Quota related information in clean csv/tabular format i.e.

- service
- Limit name
- Quota status
- Details
- Limit
- Current usage
- 7 days peak

Comment: Does this answer your questions?https://stackoverflow.com/a/63624882/11866104

Comment: Thanks but not, since it does have details as requested in above and also that is related to project quota and does not shows quota for services as listed under quota page i.e. "Cloud AutoML API "

Answer (score 0):

There is a [PIT](https://issuetracker.google.com/183706758) for this issue has been created as a Feature Request. Please feel free to post there if you have any concern regarding the issue.